# How to check if any number exists in a word

Tags: php

For example, if my word is `$item = '3.5Floppy'` or `$item = '3Floppy'` or `$item = '4520Floppy'`

I want to check whether any number exist in my word or not?

Comment: Can't you use the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function ?

Comment: for this , i need to create an array of 1 to 9 than match every number to my word..

Comment: No you don't, see the multiple answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `preg_match` is simple, is there any digit or not?

```
if(preg_match('/(\d)/', $item))
{
     echo "Number Found!";
}
```

`\d` mean is `Any digit`

Regex Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: If you want to capture the (decimal) number your capture function should perhaps be something like '/(\d+(\.\d+)?). If you don't want to capture the number the `()` are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex ([preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)):

```
$hasNumberInside = preg_match("/[0-9]/", $string);

if ($hasNumberInside === true) {
    echo 'String with number';
} else {
    echo 'No numbers inside';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo (ereg ("[0-9]{1,}", $item) ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: The `ereg` functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.